# Developing PCB for STM32F765 with 16 MHz crystal oscillator, ground plane isolation and 3.3 V plane

Tags: pcb, stm32, crystal, kicad

I have developed a PCB in Kicad for the STM32F765 microcontroller. I am using a 16 MHz crystal oscillator for the application. But I am having some confusion regarding the GND and 3.3 plane.
[image]

As shown in the image, there is a 16Mhz crystal. I want to make a 2-layer PCB since the budget is very tight.

And for the first layer, which is red if I do ground isolation.
Can I make the second whole plane 3V3, even under the crystal? or I have to avoid a 3V3 plane going under the crystal.

Thank you. I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: Most smd crystal packages that I am aware of use 1 and 3 as the "crystal" pins and the others as GND. Check the datasheet of your crystal.

Comment: Read the data sheet and if you can't understand it, please provide a link to it.

Comment: Yes ok i have changed it thank you. yes that was a mistake. Any Help regarding the plane can i have 3v3 plane under the crystal ?

Comment: Noone can give you a general answer: The 3V3 plane would shield the crystal circuit which is good, but if you have a very noisy and large current flowing through that 3V3 plane, the quartz circuit might suffer from induced currents which is bad.

Comment: Oh thank you so much. Got it